# ¿Como abrir una conexion de sql Server en C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Bueno mi problematica es que quiero abrir una conexion de sql server para asi poder hacer una consulta BD y obtener un posible resultado ya sea erroneo o acertado.

Codigo de mi metodo para autentificar usuarios:

```
public string Autentificar()
{

    string sql = @"SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nick = david AND pass = password";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ToString()))
    {
        conn.Open(); ---- Error
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn); //ejecutamos la instruccion

        int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); //devuelve la fila afectada

        if (count == 0)
            return "0";
        else
            return "1";

    }

}
```

Error que sale:

> Error de inicio de sesión del usuario ''.

Codigo de mi configuracion:

```
<configuration>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="conexion" connectionString="Data Source=NQ-ADUANA-054-V\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=bilbao;Persist Security Info=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Encierra tu código en un bloque `try/catch` y revisa el `InnerException` o `StackTrace` para obtener mas detalles del error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con esta cadena de conexión.

```
<configuration>

<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>

<connectionStrings>
 <add name="conexion" connectionString="Data Source=NQ-ADUANA-054-V\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=bilbao;Integrated Security=SSPI;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero tienes que crear una cadena de conexion creando un objeto sqlConnection, donde debes indicar los detalles de la base de datos (nombre, servidor, etc):

```
        public void GetConnection()
        {
           SqlbConnection Connection = new SqlbConnection("Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=(NOMBRE_DE_LA_BASE_DE_DATOS);server=(local O EL QUE SEA)");
            Connection.Open();                
        }
        public void CloseConnection()
        {
           SqlbConnection Connection = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=NOMBRE_DE_LA_BASE_DE_DATOS;server=local_O_EL_QUE_SEA");
            Connection.Close();
            Connection.Dispose();
        }
```

com esos metodos podras hacer las consultas. ejemplo:

```
 public void EjecutarQuery(String consulta, List<Parametros> lst)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand Comando = new SqlCommand(consulta, GetConnection());
                if (lst != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (lst[i].Dirección == ParameterDirection.Input)
                        {
                            Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue(lst[i].Nombre, lst[i].Valor);
                        }
                        if (lst[i].Dirección == ParameterDirection.Output)
                        {
                            Comando.Parameters.Add(lst[i].Nombre, lst[i].TipoDato, lst[i].Tamaño).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        }
                    }
                    GetConnection();//este metodo tiene la conexion de la base de datos
                    Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    CloseConnection();//aqui cierras la conexion
                    for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (Comando.Parameters[i].Direction == ParameterDirection.Output)
                        { lst[i].Valor = Comando.Parameters[i].Value.ToString(); }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas asegurarte que tu cadena de conexión este bien formada:

```
<add name="conexion" 
connectionString="Data Source=servidor\instancia;Initial Catalog=BASE_DE_DATOS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USUARIO;Password=CONTRASEÑA;Max Pool Size=40" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

También asegurate de que el usuario que configuraste tenga acceso a la base de datos. Esto lo puedes probar intentando hacer login con **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio** a tu base de datos.

Para configurar la seguridad mediante SQL Server Authentication puedes seguir este tutorial:
[Habilitar Autenticación SQL](https://www.slideshare.net/narkamo3/habilitar-la-autenticacin-sql-y-crear-un-nuevo-usuario-sql)

Comment: cuando entro a sql no uso ni contraseña ni usuario, solo uso mi instancia. necesito crea alguno para poder acceder a una base de datos, no hay una forma como en mysql de que sea root mi usuario y no poner mi contraseña, usa un inicio de sesion por defecto.

Comment: a la hora de instalar el SQLExpress utiliza tu usuario admin como el administrador de la base de datos, regularmente en desarrollo se activa la seguridad mediante SQL Server Authentication para crear usuarios especificos para las bases de datos.